# Finding combinations pairs of list items forward

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a input list,

```
n = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48] 
# Here, the list is multiples of 6 
# but need not always be, could be of different numbers or unrelated.
```

Now I would like to generate pair of numbers from the list so the output is,

```
output = [(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

I have below snippet to get it done.

```
zip([(i+1) for i in n[:-1]], n[1:])
```

Just out of curious, I would like to know the other approaches than what I have!

Comment: If you use pandas, this is as simple as `pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(n, closed='left')`.

Comment: Another option that looks uglier than your list comp is using `zip` + `map`: `list(zip(map(lambda x: x + 1, n), n[1:]))`

Comment: You could always write it as: `[(x+1, y) for x, y in zip(n[:-1], n[1:])]`. Other than that, looks great.

Comment: Also, you don't even need the `n[:-1]`, because `zip` by default zips only upto the shorter of the two lists. So, `zip([(i+1) for i in n], n[1:])` works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have right now is pretty good (in my books). Although, you could substitute the `n[:-1]` with `n`, because `zip` performs a "shortest possible zipping" - zips upto the shorter of the two lists -

```
>>> list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

So, you could rewrite your expression as -

```
list(zip([(i+1) for i in n], n[1:]))
```

For conciseness. Drop the `list(..)` for python 2.

An alternative ([suggested by RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020089/finding-combinations-pairs-of-list-items-forward/48020212#comment83009285_48020089)), would be to bring the list comprehension out, and the `zip` in -

```
>>> [(x + 1, y) for x, y in zip(n, n[1:])]
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

Or, you can get rid of `zip` completely (as [suggested by splash58](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020089/finding-combinations-pairs-of-list-items-forward/48020212#comment83011775_48020212)), by using positional based indexing -

```
>>> [(n[i] + 1, n[i + 1]) for i in range(len(n) - 1)]
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

---

Another way to do this is using the functional programming paradigm, with `map` -

```
>>> list(zip(map(lambda x: x + 1, n), n[1:]))
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

Which does the same thing your list comp does, but probably slower!

---

And finally, if you use `pandas` (my favourite library), then you can leverage the `IntervalIndex` API -

```
>>> pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(n, closed='right')
IntervalIndex([(0, 6], (6, 12], (12, 18], (18, 24], (24, 30], (30, 36], (36, 42], (42, 48]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

Comment: thanks. Great with pandas and got to know about `zip` function

Comment: for collection :)  `[ [n[x] + 1, n[x+1]] for x in range(len(n)-1)]`

Answer (score 3):

Another one as numpy accepts integer addition:

```
import numpy as np

n = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48] 
a = np.array(n)
output = list(zip(a+1,a[1:]))

print(output)
```

Returns:

```
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's recommendation of the functional programming paradigm, you could also use `map()` without `zip()` to do this:

```
n = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48] 

result = list(map(lambda x, y: (x + 1, y), n, n[1:]))

print(result)
# [(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n1=range(0,49)
n=n1[1::6]
x1=range(1,44)
x=x1[::6]
print (zip(x,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
final_list=[]
n = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48]
for i in range(0,len(n),1):
    chuck=n[i:i+2]
    if len(chuck)<2:
        pass
    else:
        final_list.append((chuck[0]+1,chuck[1]))
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[(1, 6), (7, 12), (13, 18), (19, 24), (25, 30), (31, 36), (37, 42), (43, 48)]
```

You can also do in one line:

```
n = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48]
print([(n[i:i+2][0]+1,n[i:i+2][1]) for i in range(0,len(n),1) if len(n[i:i+2])==2])
```